# MySQL. How to extract strings and numbers from a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring, etl

I have a database from customers with a column called "BUTTON" with the name of a button and the number of clicks that user has clicked.

COLUMN BUTTON

1. NULL
2. {Red-Button=1, Exit-Button=1, Info-Button=1}
3. {New-Button=1}
4. NULL
5. {Red-Button=1, Info-Button=1}
6. {Appstore-Button=1, Exit-Button=1}

***What I need?***
A row with TWO COLUMNS. **BUTTON** for every Button name and **CLICKS** for the number of clicks for every button

I need to extract every name and the number (after the '=' character).
I tried substring_index but I have problems with the '{' and I don't obtain every button, only one.

Comment: The right answer is to not store data in that format,  store data in a properly normalised format, or at the very least using something like JSON that mysql can parse natively. Or write some sort of script to convert the data and put it into that format.  Writing that is too broad for an SO answer.